# Vala: Convert int to uint16

Tags: gtk, vala

How do I convert from int to uint16 in vala?

My requirement is to convert the text in decimal in a gtkEntry to uint16.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast. `uint16 as_uint16 = (uint16) as_int;`

You may want to first check that the value is between `uint16.MIN` and `uint16.MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myint = 543;    
uint16 z = 0 + myint;
```